# Which algorithm is used to train/predict Opencv LBPH face recognizer?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I couldn't understand how  training stage and predition stage is working.İs it using another algorithm like svm or k-nearestneighbour after finding LBPH features?

Answer (score 0):

If you check: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/lbph_faces.cpp
Then you will see they use 1-nearest neighbour, excerpt from detect function:

```
// find 1-nearest neighbor
collector->init((int)_histograms.size(), state);
for (size_t sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < _histograms.size(); sampleIdx++) {
    double dist = compareHist(_histograms[sampleIdx], query, HISTCMP_CHISQR_ALT);
    int label = _labels.at<int>((int)sampleIdx);
    if (!collector->collect(label, dist, state))return;
}
```

A 1-nearest neighbour classifier is used since the Local Binary Pattern descriptor is simple enough. See for a more in depth explanation the paper: "*Face Recognition with Local Binary Patterns*"

On a side note. This is not really an implementation/practical question and thus does not really belong on this forum. I would suggest using the opencv forum.